# gfortran specify source file option

Tags: gcc, gfortran, compiler-options

In `gcc` we have `-x` option that use to specify how to treat source file.

For example suppose we have a `csourcecode` file without any extension like .c.

In `gcc` simply using `-x c` before express `csourcecode` force compiler to use it as valid c source code.

`gcc -x c csourcecode -o out`

Is there any similar option for `gfortran`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the helpful [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-x): [Note 1]

> You can specify the input language explicitly with the `-x` option:
>
> -x *language*
>
> Specify explicitly the *language* for the following input files
> (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the
> file name suffix).  This option applies to all following input
> files until the next `-x` option.  Possible values for *language*
> are:
>
> ***(snip)***
>
> ```
>      f77  f77-cpp-input f95  f95-cpp-input
> ```

If you're using a Unix-y system and you took the precaution of installing the gcc documentation package (`apt-get install gcc-doc` on debian/ubuntu-like systems), then you could have found that information directly by typing

```
info gcc --index-search=x
```

because the GCC info files are index by option name. Most of the time you don't need to type `--index-search=`; `info gcc x` would suffice.

---

#### Notes:

1. In case it's not obvious, `gfortran` is just another front-end for the Gnu compiler collection ("gcc" for short), and accepts any options that would be accepted by the `gcc` command.